# How to change the value of data inside a struct through a function?

Tags: c

first time posting here, any help would be appreciated. I'm trying to change the value "size" inside my stack called "try", by putting it through my function called Stack_Init. If I print out the value of "stack->size" inside the function, it gives me the correct value for size (being 4). If I were to print
`try->size` after executing my function (at the end of the code), it would give me a value of 0.

```
struct intnode {
    int data;
    struct intnode *next; 
}; typedef struct intnode node; 

struct stack {
    node *top;     
    int size;
}; typedef struct stack Stack;

void Stack_Init(Stack *S, int size){
    Stack *stack = malloc(size*sizeof(node)); 
    stack->top = NULL;
    stack->size = size;//for some reason, this doesn't change try->size
}
int main(){
    Stack *try;
    int size = 4;
    Stack_Init(try,size);
    printf("%d %d ", try->size, try->top);
```

Thanks for reading!

Comment: `Stack *stack = malloc(size*sizeof(node));`. That's a local variable. It has no relation to `try` in `main`. Why do you think it would? Most beginners make the mistake of doing `S = stack`. That is also wrong because `S` is local to the function.  But you aren't even doing that so not sure how you expect that `stack` would get back to `main`.

Comment: I previously had it as 'S' instead of stack, but it didn't change anything in main either. Looking at it now it doesn't make any sense, how do I relate try to the function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to change a pointer that you pass to the function, so you need an extra level of indirection, i.e. a pointer to pointer. In addition, you need to assign to dereferenced parameter instead of a local variable:

```
void Stack_Init(Stack **S, int size){
    //                 ^
    //                 |
    //        Extra asterisk here
    *S = malloc(size*sizeof(node)); 
//  ^
//  |
// Dereference the pointer passed into the function
    (*S)->top = NULL;
    (*S)->size = size;
}
```

The call to the function needs to look like this:

```
Stack_Init(&try,size);
//         ^
//         |
// Pass a pointer to a pointer
```

Comment: "You are trying to change a pointer that you pass to the function". Nit pick. OP is not doing even that.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, really appreciate it!

Comment: You don't need to change the function signature.  `Stack **S` implies you have a list of `Stack *`s.  Besides, you're using the parameter `&try` to make the `Stack *` to a `Stack **`.  It just complicates things.

Comment: @kamoroso94 You do need to change the signature. It wouldn't work without it.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Stack_Init` function has a couple problems with it.  You are modifying a local variable instead of the argument passed to the function, and you're assigning the memory incorrectly.  Try this instead.

```
void Stack_Init(Stack **S,int size) {
    Stack *stack = (Stack*)malloc(sizeof(Stack));
    stack->top = NULL;
    stack->size = size;
    *S = stack;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for bringing this to my attention.  You're quite right.

Comment: Very true.  I modified the function to reflect that and make it more similar to the code in the question.